# Explain why "of" should be used

Tags: prepositions

I hired an American freelancer to explain prepositions to me. She said that I should use "of" in both sentences because "of" means "out of". I understand that in Sentence 1, it means "out of the three appliances". But the meaning of "out of" doesn't make any sense to me in Sentence 2. I think it doesn't make sense to say "the highest percentage out of the three appliances". I mean that "percentage out of appliances" doesn't make sense. Then she said that in Sentence 2, "of" means “compared to the other appliances.” But I've never heard this definition before. Can you help me understand the use of "of" in Sentence 2. I originally used "among".

> 1. Washing machines were the most common **of** the three electrical
>    appliances in 1920, with ownership reaching 40% of households.

> 2. 40% of households owned a washing machine in 1920, the highest **of**
>    the three electrical appliances that year.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that saying "**Of** means **out of**" is particularly helpful here. It's just the preposition that we use in English when comparing one member of a group to the rest. "I am the eldest of three sisters." 40% is the highest of the three percentage figures for ownership of electrical appliances.

Comment: _Of_ is often a sort of "general purpose" preposition, with little meaning of its own. I think that trying to tease out a precise meaning in different uses is going to be a waste of time.  I prefer _among_ to _of_ in your second sentence.

Comment: Thank you both. @ColinFine, but I asked several native speakers and they all said "of" should be used. I'm not asking for a precise meaning. I am just trying to understand why "of" should be used so that next time I can use it correctly. If I don't understand it, I will make mistakes next time.

Comment: @KateBunting, do you mean you agree that "of" is better than "among" in Sentence 2? And do you mean that my interpretation of "highest percentage of the three appliances" is wrong. I should interpret it as "highest percentage of the three percentages"?

Comment: You can use _among_, but _of_ is simpler and more usual. Sentence (2) could have been better expressed; the meaning is obvious in context, but what is being compared is not three appliances but the _percentage of households owning_ those three appliances.

Comment: @KateBunting, thank you very much. I think I finally understand the use of "of" in Sentence 2.